# Javascript - fade to display:none

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to fade a d3 chord in a chord diagram to `display:none`

It works if I use the css class:

```
#circle:hover path.fade {
opacity: .03;
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
```

however, this does not work with `display:none`. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Ah this is a duplicate - missed the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no animation for changing the `display` attribute. You can smoothly transition opacity, but there's no possibility of changing the `display` smoothly.

To circumvent this you can transition both opacity and height at the same time, but this would require first setting the height or using javascript to change the height.

Comment: This is where `visibility` comes handy!  You can also use `visibility: hidden` too!